# Can we access the elements in webview and fill the blocks and make it click submit automatically

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Basically want to create an Android app which open the particular website and Fills in the details in the form provided and submit without any human interaction how is it possible..

Comment: you likely don't need a WebView for that. You can just check which request the web page sends, and perform same request from Android device

Comment: How? I'm not too much into field can u explain thanks in advance

Comment: `How?` what exactly? my comment contains too much subjects to `How?` question to answer all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can load urls with the function webView.loadUrl and submit data (eg. inside a form) with the function webView.postUrl. See the docs for more info